# How to georeference TIFFs with coordinates from txt file using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff, text, geotag

I have a folder with TIFFs and an accompanying .txt file containing coordinates in this format (sample):

```
    # IMGE       LN   ID             Time         Easting      Northing       Height       Phi      Omega      Kappa 
    \00381.tif   2111 21110038       385850.277   32356528.276 5642849.274    1518.200     47.7391   -0.0656    100.1021
    \00391.tif   2111 21110039       385854.176   32356526.170 5643123.992    1517.967     47.7847   -0.1409    100.1607
```

The images themselves contain no info - the image name is the only connection I have. The images also overlap, so I can't put them together manually, at least not without a lot of work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the source of the text file? I Googled a few column heading terms and wound up [here](https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/202558539-Input-Files). From what I see in the information you have, you cannot georeference the images because you have no origin point. You've got Easting and Northing which could be meters or feet, so you could get them relative to each other. But without an origin point (east/north of where, for example maybe a specific UTM zone? more likely a custom local CRS) you have no way of placing them in the world.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I have a PDF map showing the image centers (dots with image numbers) but couldn't come up with any way to use them. I figured if I couldn't get the single images referenced I might at least align them relative to each other, join and then work from there.

Comment: Chris is 100% correct, there is no image 'from' coordinate, what you have is camera information which can be used in conjunction with a DEM/DTM to orthorectify (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthophoto) the images using specialist software. If you don't have such then contact the vendor for the orthorectified images or seek out a company who does have the software to do it for you (for a modest fee)... the software is *very* expensive for a one-off; GRASS may be able to do it with i.ortho.photo module but I can't comment on that having not used it.

Comment: I see. I guess this is the closest answer that can be given, given the current data. Thanks, both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information present in the text file is not sufficient to georeference the images. After Googling some of the column headings and arriving at [this page](https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/202558539-Input-Files), it appears what you're given are easting/northing coordinates for (apparently) the image centers. Eastings and northings are coordinates as measured from a specific origin point in either a standard projection (like a UTM zone) or possibly (and perhaps more likely in this case) a completely custom CRS for the specific project. Since you don't have the lat/lon of the origin, you could only use them for locating the images relative to each other. It's also unclear if they're meters or feet.

The information you have appears to be image name, image grid row id,  image id, time taken, distance east of origin, distance north of origin, camera altitude, and three variables related to camera look angle and distortion. This suggests, as Michael mentions, the images are not already orthorectified and therefore still have perspective distortion in them. The pdf map doesn't really help you either unless it labels the coordinates of the images - otherwise it's just a quick reference to what order the images are relative to each other.

You might be able to georeference your pdf map, assuming it has more details than just a grid with labeled points in it, and then use that to get the actual lat/lon coordinates of the image centers. But because of the suspected perspective distortion, your best bet for anything approaching accurate is going to be to georeference the images individually. You might also consider a service aimed at working with UAV imagery which can process the raw images into georeferenced and orthorectified images - for example http://dronemapper.com/ I have no connection with them and there are other options, including DIY 'hobbyist' software you can find by searching.